# Proving DeMorgan's Theorem

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove that (without using logical equivalencies):

$\overline{A\cap B} = \bar A \cup \bar B$

by proving both sides:

(1) $ x \in \overline{A\cap B} \to x \in \bar A\cup\bar B$

(2) $ x \in \bar A\cup\bar B \to x \in \overline{A\cap B}$

I figured out the 2nd part, but I'm struggling with the first. The only thing I'm confident about now is:

Let $x \in \overline{A\cap B}$. We prove that $x \in \bar A\cup \bar B$. By definition of complement, $x \not\in A\cap B$.

I'm not sure if I should use cases, or if I should prove by contradictions. With the other variation of DeMorgan's, I could assume $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ and they would lead to contradictions with the first assumption, but I can't do that here because it's a $\cap$ instead of a $\cup$.

For reference, here's the proof I was given for the other variation of DeMorgan's:

Prove: $\overline{A \cup B} = \bar A \cap \bar B$

(1) if $x \in \overline{A \cup B}$ then $x \in \bar A \cap \bar B$

(2) if $x \in \bar A \cap \bar B$ then $x \in \overline{A \cup B}$

Proof:

(1)Let $x \in \overline{A \cup B}$. We prove that $x \in \bar A \cap \bar B$. By definition of complement, $x \not\in A \cup B$. Suppose, for contradiction, $x \not\in \bar A$. By definition of complement, $x \in A$, and by definition of union, $x \in A\cup B$, a contradiction. Thus, $x \in \bar A$. Now, suppose for contradiction, $x \not\in \bar B$. By definition of complement, $x \in B$, and by definition of union, $x \in A \cup B$, a contradiction. So, $x \in \bar B$. Therefore, $x \in \bar A$ and $x \in \bar B$, so by definition of intersection, $x \in \bar A \cap \bar B$.

(I'm leaving out the 2nd part, as I've figured out the 2nd part in my problem above)

Any ideas? I'm assuming it has to be of similar complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in \overline{A\cap B}$. Then, by definition, $x\notin A\cap B$, thus $x\notin A$ or $x\notin B$. For suppose to the contrary, that $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. Then it is the case that $x\in A\cap B$, hence $x\notin \overline{A\cap B}$, a contradiction to our assumption. So we have $x\in\overline{A}$ or $x\in\overline{B}$; combining these two, we have $x\in\overline{A}\cup \overline{B}$.

Comment: I don’t understand the downvote; so far as I can see, this is exactly the sort of answer that is expected.

Comment: I believe the downvote came before his edits. I think with the edits this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Actually, how am I able to claim that x is not in A or x is not in B from x is not in A intersect B? Isn't that using DeMorgan's?

Comment: @ekweible: That is the contradiction. If $x\notin A$ or $x\notin B$, we're happy and can proceed. Suppose this is not the case; then it must be the case that $x\in A\cap B$ (otherwise it is not in one of them). This says that $x\notin \overline{A\cap B}$, a contradiction.

Comment: Oh okay, I get it. Thank you very much! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you've got $x\notin A\cap B$ correct. If you're allowed to use the variation on DeMorgan's you were given. $A\cap B = \overline{\bar{A}\cup \bar{B}},$ from which $x\notin \overline{\bar{A}\cup \bar{B}},$ so $x\in \bar{A} \cup \bar{B}.$ If you're not, then just prove the other variation and use it :)

Comment: I don't think I'm allowed to do that, isn't that like using DeMorgan's? This is the stipulation given for this problem: You may not use logical equivalences in your proof. Use general proof techniques
like proof by contradiction and proof by cases since a direct proof will not work.

Comment: Ah okay - I will edit

Answer (score 0):

DeMorgan revolves around two principles

1. $\sim \forall x P(x) \iff \exists x \sim P(x)$.
2. $\sim \exists x P(x) \iff \forall x \sim P(x)$.

That's all folks!

Answer (score 0):

$n \in \overline{A \cap B}$.

then $n \not \in A \cap B$

$n$ may exist in either $A$ or in $B$ but not both.

We can then be certain that $n \in \overline{A}$ or $n \in \overline{B}$.

Because the element $n$ is contained in either $\overline{A}$ or $\overline{B}$ we can be sure that $\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$ contains the element $n$.

$n \in \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$

so $n \not\in A \cup B$ thus $n \not \in A $ or $n \not \in B$

we can then determine $n \not \in A \cap B$.

Finally by the definition of a complement we can state that $n \in \overline{A \cap B}$  which proves our theorem that $\overline{A \cap B}= \bar A \cup \bar B$.